# Regular expression that allows me to match all but the defined substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

testInputs.abc_def.alpha=abc^ORtestVars.var23.nameISEMPTY^testInputs.alpha_bravo.more.otheroneCONTAINSsomething^testVars.anotherone!=abc^testVars.mYVar!=abc

I need it to match

`testInputs.abc_def.alpha`
`testVars.var23.name`
`testInputs.alpha_bravo.more.otherone`
`testVars.anotherone`
`testVars.mYVar`

I can match all occurences, but the problem is that it also matches some operators that it shouldnt:

ISEMPTY
CONTAINS

(And a slew of others like IN, NOT IN, etc.)

I have an array that I can join to create an alternation, but the issue is maintaining the match, without the prohibted substrings. As it stands now instead of

`testVars.var23.name`

I end up with

`testVars.var23.nameISEMPTY`

Similarly, I match `testInputs.alpha_bravo.more.otheroneCONTAINS`

The rules as it stands are:

- Match can start with `testInputs.` or `testVars.`
- Any alpha numeric, regardless of case, as well as underscores(_) and periods(.)
- The substring after the testInputs or testVars can be any length
- There can be multiple matches in a string
- The match can also be in the form of {{var}} e.g {{testInputs.myinput}}=abc or {{testVars.my_var}}ISEMPTY, but I have left the above clear of that so it's easier to read.

So far I have tried the following:

`(({{)?(?:testInputs\.|testVars\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+(}})?)`

And tried a few variations of the lookahead/behind

`(?!CONTAINS|ISEMPTY)`

But have been unsuccessful in excluding the Invalid substrings, while still matching the piece of the match I'm looking for.

Comment: How does one even end up with a string like this?

Comment: You have not stated the rules for matching strings precisely. See my answer for an example of how you might go about doing that. Both answers posted to date are based on assumptions. It would be helpful if you would post a comment on each answer that states whether the assumptions made are correct, and if they are not, how they should be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match each character with a negative lookhead pattern to exclude known keywords (feel free to add more):

```
(?:testInputs|testVars)\.(?:[\w.](?!ISEMPTY|CONTAINS|OR|IN|[^\w.]))*\w
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/L14Te5/3

Answer (score 1):

You can match the following regular expression:

```
test(?:Inputs|Vars)\.(?:(?=.*test(?:Inputs|Vars)\.)[^!=A-Z]+|(?!.*test(?:Inputs|Vars)\.)[^!=]+)
```

provided these three rules apply:

- The match begins `'testInputs.'` or `'testVars.'`.
- Following the match of `'testInputs.'` or `'testVars.'`, if one of those strings appears later in the string, as many characters as possible in the character class `[^!=A-Z]` are matched.
- Following the match of `'testInputs.'` or `'testVars.'`, if neither of those strings appears later in the string, as many characters as possible in the character class `[^!=]` are matched.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VBxZHb/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
test(?:Inputs|Vars)\.          # match literal
(?:                            # begin non-capture group
  (?=.*test(?:Inputs|Vars)\.)  # positive lookahead asserts literal appears
                               # later in the string
  [^!=A-Z]+                    # match one or more chars in the char class
|                              # or
  (?!.*test(?:Inputs|Vars)\.)  # negative lookahead asserts literal does not
                               # appear later in the string
  [^!=]+                       # match one or more chars in the char class
)                              # end non-capture group
```

Comment: Have to say that making the assumption that uppercase attribute names can appear only in the last expression is a really fragile generalization and would only work for the very test case in the question. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VBxZHb/2 Sadly the input for this question is so screwed up that there is simply no generalized solution but to exhaustively include all the known keywords in the pattern.

Comment: @blhsing, I just reverse-engineered the sole example to get the assumptions and from there the regex. I doubt that my assumptions are correct but perhaps the OP might be able to adapt the approach. The problem is when questions are stated in terms of an example (as are so many, sadly) they rarely are clear.

Comment: Yes, the question is far from clear, but at least in this case I don't think it's hard for us experienced programmers to tell what each token in the input string represents, and it just isn't right to assume that an attribute name can contain an uppercase letter only if it's in the last expression. No programming language is designed like that.